# Image Picker using Camera in Landscape not working properly (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

My Image Picker does work with the Photo library in both orientations, but using the camera it doesn't adjust correctly to landscape.

This is how it looks:
Landscape:
[image: Problematic Camera View]
Portrait:
[image: Camera View That Looks Normal]

Here is My Code:

File1, UIViewControllerRepresentable:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary

@Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
    imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return imagePicker
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
    
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}



final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    
    var parent: ImagePicker
    
    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            parent.selectedImage = image
        }
        
        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
}
```

File 2, Using It:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary) {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: .camera, selectedImage: self.$image)
        }
```

I am not fixed on using a fullScreenCover, just did that because it worked at least partially.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?

Comment: @LiborZapletal No Solution yet, but I found out that it seems to be a Problem only on some devices. On my iPhone 7 it seems to work fine while on the 11 it does not.

Comment: any updates to this with iOS15? I've got the same issue. My app is portrait only, but want to allow for landscape photo capture from camera.

Comment: I have the same issue. Given answer did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

there maybe a workaround solution, but according to the Apple docs:

"The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. ...."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

Maybe you could use:

```
let theCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
```

This works quite well.

Comment: Could you elaboate on how you're doing this using AVCaptureDevice?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about this is to create a specific view that calls your ImagePicker, and lock that view in portrait mode.

First, in the AppDelegate, add this, which I learned from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNY6C9-QWCI

```
   static var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return AppDelegate.orientationLock
    }
```

Then, make the view, ImagePickerView for example

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePickerView: View {
    
    @State private var image = UIImage()
  
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: .camera, selectedImage: $image)
        }
        .onAppear() {
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
            AppDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            AppDelegate.orientationLock = .all
        }
    }
        
}

struct ImagePickerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ImagePickerView()
    }
}
```

and to call the ImagePicker/camera from another view, just call ImagePickerView() and it should work well